# My Mac crashes every time I shutdown. What may be causing this?

Tags: macos, catalina, crash, kernel-panic

My Mac crashes every time I shutdown.

I have an iMac iMac (27-inch, Late 2012), 24 GB of RAM, 500GB of disk free.

I find dozens of crash files named `Kernel_....._mercury.gpuRestart` (mercury is my computer's name) at `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`. These files contain something like:

```
Wed Apr  8 15:47:48 2020

Event:               GPU Reset
Date/Time:           Wed Apr  8 15:47:48 2020
Application:         com.apple.WebKit
Path:                /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Tailspin:            /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/gpuRestart2020-04-08-154748.tailspin
GPUSubmission Trace ID: 0
Version:             15609.1.20.111.8
OS Version:          Mac OS X Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E266)
Graphics Hardware:   NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660M
Signature:           45

Report Data:

NVDA(Graphics): Channel exception! Exception type = 0x45 Graphics Engine Error (GR Class Error)
Channel Info: [96, 0x52, 0x50, 0x81f]
Version Info: [com.apple.GeForce, 14.0.0, 0x4e554e, 22469702, 355.11.11.10.10.143, 1]
ErrorDB Hash: [70ced8266b6e91e895714fe37e4dc1bd]

Resource Manager Info:
 4443564e 000000d0 fbe5dba1 b08da789 00000001 00000014 d3793533 46d3a4a6
 4614f297 e71edccf 00088301 0000009a 12f2240a 081f0a21 1002c197 18408080
 28002000 38003004 80404780 004840c7 52580050 030a0060 0a00149a 0713820a
 01500318 0a010190 3a13923d 0024380a 000e0000 e0010000 0f490000 00010000
 0b490000 00000000 04470000 00ff0003 00ff0000 00ff0000 00ff0000 00ff0000
 00ff0000 220a0000 081f13c2 18001000 f4bc80a8 2852200b 38033045 c9805000
 c89bcdbc 02804001 00000348 4443564e
```

Also This other file called `WindowServer_2020-04-10-035028_mercury.userspace_watchdog_timeout`is also there with this content:

https://cl1p.net/mercury1

and also other files named `WindowServer_2020-04-10-040644_mercury.crash` and `WindowServer_2020-04-10-035028_mercury.userspace_watchdog_timeout.spin`.

any ideas what may be causing this annoying crashes?